# Stopping a recursive function in JAVA (from within a thread)

Tags: java, multithreading

I think that this question has been brought up a few times in the past, but this is a little different and i could not find an appropriate answer anywhere.
I have a thread which calls (inside `run()`)  another recursive function. This is actually a game engine and the recursive function is MiniMax.
The problem is, that when the user wants to Resign a game in the middle of the calculation, or even Undo a move, then how should I stop this function?

I cannot interrupt the thread with a `boolean`, since if the call to Minimax has already been made, then the program is inside this function and the thread will not check the interruption condition in order to termintate, calling `interrupt()` also does not work.

How do I stop such a function?

Comment: The `Minimax` function is binary only?  You don't have source?  Really, it's this function (recursive or not) that should be polling on some flag to determine if it should continue or abandon it's work.

Comment: Im having trouble fully understanding the situation. Can you post a snippet with the irrelevant code removed?

Comment: There is no way. Either check the `boolean` on each recursive step. Or, better, check for the interrupt flag on the thread on each step.

Comment: Why can't you do it with a `boolean`? If you have thread's reference just modify its value and stop the recursion

Comment: so i need to put a boolean inside the Minimax function itself?    but but what if i have like a 4000000 recursive calls on the stack, they all get terminated while i change this flag?     would this be ok?

Comment: If you have so many calls on the stack, you probably already have a StackOverflowError. Why would it be a problem to stop everything, since that's precisely what you want?

Comment: I came across that idea but I guess i didn't took it seriously enough.  probably because i haven't seen any Minimax code exampe with a conditional looop inside   (this is a little like Iterative deepening framework).      
It seems that this is the only way

Comment: What happens when you "stop" is up to you... but you've indicated that you WANT it to stop, so do you, or don't you?

Comment: Thanks,I actually put a loop inside the Minimax function with a boolean: interrupted ;  when i change it,I just tell the function to return some fake score, but i am not doing anything with it.  so Thanks for all the replies,the problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Calling Thread.interrupt() will throw InterruptedException at any wait() or sleep() that you call from the thread proccess, also remember to check isInterrupted() to "not do things".

When InterrupedException is thrown from sleep/wait (or join) the interrupted status is cleared, and a call for isInterruped() will return false, so remember to interrupt() the Thread after the Exception.

Also, using boolean interrupted() instead of isInterrupted() does clear interruped status, and a double check with interrupted may result in true following by false if not interrupted again between calls.

PS: One more suggestion, if interrupt is not enough, you can has a Queue that you can send messages and consume it from the running thread and interpret the value to stop the proccess (note that it's not a static flag, it's a Queue or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is actually getting aroung the problem, not too elegant, but quite creative. I found it in the source code of junit's  [FailOnTimeout](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/FailOnTimeout.java) statement. What they do is to wrap a [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) in a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) then launch it using a thread. Then they call `FutureTask.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` which returns the result or throws a `TimeoutException` if `timeout` `units` passed and lets the thread run as long as it wants. I think the same idea could be used here as well.